# Django: Drop-down list value that is not on the list

Tags: html, django, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to input a value into drop-down list that is NOT on the list using `Django`. A default value is read from the database.
But the trick is, that the user can see the value, but not change to it.

Is there a way to do it with `Django`?
`Django` won't allow me to display in drop-down list something that is not defined in `models.py`, so the object remains empty.

Any ideas? Maybe some walk-around?

Thanks

Code:

```
aList = (('OK', 'OK'), ('Not', 'Not'))

class sampleModel(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
  res = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, choices=aList)
```

From another database comes entry OK* and Not*. I need to display that OK*/Not* in drop-down list but so that user cannot use it, but still can change to normal OK/Not.

Comment: Hi, some code and an example would be nice.

Comment: I'd go for either custom validation for the "res" field in a form, or disable all values but OK/Not with JavaScript. Or both.

Answer (score 1):

One simple option could be to add an empty choice to your choices like:

```
aList = (
    ('', 'OK/Not') 
    ('OK', 'OK'), 
    ('Not', 'Not')
)
```

and make the  field `res` to be required, so that you cannot pass an empty value, so if the user selects the empty choice, the form will return error until he choose one of the valid choices

You should change your field:

```
res = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, choices=aList)
```

for:

```
res = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=aList)
```

The only change made was to remove **blank=True** so the field is requried.

All of this assuming you have some Django ModelForm that you generated based on your model

Other option to avoid modifying the model could be to manage the select in the view. If you have the select in the HTML with 3 choiceS:

```
<select name="mySelect" id="id_mySelect">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Please select value</option>
  <option value="value1">Ok</option>
  <option value="value2">Not</option>
</select>
```

So when you receive the POST in your view, you could do something like:

```
error = False
error_text = ''
# Manually get the value of the select in your view
myselect = request.POST.get('mySelect', None)

# If the value of the select is '' return an error to the template
if not myselect:
   error = True
   error_text = 'You have to select an option'
   return ('yourtemplate.html', {'error':error, 'error_text': error_text}, context_instance=RequestContext(request) )
```

and you only need to manage that custom error you're returning to the template

You really have a lot possibilities to do what you're trying to do, but to help us helping you we need more information about your project, usually some parts of the code you have right now and how are you managing it too.

Options to do what you want:

- Make the field required and use ModelForm
- Make a custom form and customize the field validation (as @dukeboy suggested)
- Make the select pure HTML and manage it on the view
- ...